# I want someone to write a short piece of code storing query string data in a DB using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Before anything pops up in your mind, please understand that I am very new to PHP and to be honest, I am depending exclusively on stack overflow to build my simple and first php web application.

I am trying to get the data from a query string and store it in my database. I want someone to write a short piece of code to check whether the string exists and if it does, add it to my database. I am using wordprss so i think we can use $_GET and $wpdb but i don't know the syntax. The url with querystring is something like:
http://www.mydomain.tld/?publishid=1235ABC

Comment: Have you tried searching StackOverflow for "php wordpress query"? You'll find many examples, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386082/php-wordpress-query Welcome!

Comment: In the last 11 years, I have learnt so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to given address http://www.mydomain.tld/?publishid=1235ABC it would be something like below::

```
    <?php
       $input = isset($_GET['publishid']) ? $_GET['publishid'] : '';
       if(!empty($input)) {
          $query = "INSERT INTO table (input_field) VALUES ('$input')";
          mysql_query($query);
       }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would check if the publishid exists in the GET variable.  The rest depends on which database you are using, and what do you want to do if it doesn't exist.

```
if(!isset($_GET['publishid']))
{
       //Do whatever you want if the key does not exists
}
else
{
//Insert into the database.  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

love the answers from ([bariz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5610650/2891692) and [Nobita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5610624/2891692)) and love this little modification

```php
        <?php
           if(!empty($_GET['publishid'])) {
              $input = $_GET['publishid'];
              $query = "INSERT INTO table (input_field) VALUES ('$input')";
              mysql_query($query);
           }
        ?>
```